# Problems with Scala Numeric[T]

Tags: scala, types

I have a numeric solving function (`Double => Double`) where I tried to be clever and use the `Numeric[T]` for keeping the two kinds of numbers apart.

This did not turn out to be easy. The remaining problems are:

- how to do division; `Numeric[T]` only has plus, minus etc. operators.
- why doesn't the compiler find the `implicit evidence$1: Numeric[Double]` functions (see compiler output below)

Ideally, I'd like to say, "`A` and `B` are both `Double`, but tell me if I mix them with each other".

Here's the code:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

class Sweep[A: Numeric, B: Numeric]( fDiff: A => B, initialSeed: A, initialStep: A, bEps: B )
{
  val anum= evidence$1
  val bnum= evidence$2

  assert( anum.signum(initialStep) > 0 )
  assert( bnum.lt( fDiff(initialSeed), fDiff( anum.plus(initialSeed,initialStep) )) )   // check that it's an increasing function

  @tailrec
  private def sweep( seed: A, step: A ): A = {
    val bDiff= fDiff(seed)

    if ( bnum.lt( bnum.abs(bDiff), bEps) ) {  // done
      seed
    } else if ( bnum.signum(bDiff) != anum.signum(step) ) {
      sweep( anum.plus(seed,step), step )   // continue, same step and direction ('bDiff' should go smaller)
    } else {
      val newStep = anum.toDouble(step) / -2.0
      sweep( anum.minus(seed,newStep), newStep )    // reverse, smaller step
    }
  }

  // Make sure we take the initial step in the right direction
  //  
  private lazy val stepSign= -bnum.signum( fDiff(initialSeed) )

  def apply: A = sweep( initialSeed, stepSign * initialStep )
}

object TestX extends App {

  val t= new Sweep( (a: Double) => (a*a)-2, 1.0, 0.5, 1e-3 )()

  println( t, math.sqrt(2.0) )
}
```

I've tried it also with the older `(implicit anum: Numeric[A])` parameters, but was unable to have two such (both for `A` and `B`).

Here's what the compiler says (Scala 2.9):

```
fsc -deprecation -d out-make -unchecked src/xxx.scala
src/xxx.scala:25: error: type mismatch;
 found   : newStep.type (with underlying type Double)
 required: A
      sweep( anum.minus(seed,newStep), newStep )    // reverse, smaller step
                             ^
src/xxx.scala:33: error: overloaded method value * with alternatives:
  (x: Double)Double <and>
  (x: Float)Float <and>
  (x: Long)Long <and>
  (x: Int)Int <and>
  (x: Char)Int <and>
  (x: Short)Int <and>
  (x: Byte)Int
 cannot be applied to (A)
  def apply: A = sweep( initialSeed, stepSign * initialStep )
                                              ^
src/xxx.scala:38: error: not enough arguments for constructor Sweep: (implicit evidence$1: Numeric[Double], implicit evidence$2: Numeric[Double])Sweep[Double,Double].
Unspecified value parameters evidence$1, evidence$2.
  val t= new Sweep( (a: Double) => (a*a)-2, 1.0, 0.5, 1e-3 )()
         ^
three errors found
```

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to be working with `Fractional` instead of `Numeric`. The following compiles for me:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
import math.Fractional.Implicits._
import Ordering.Implicits._

class Sweep[A: Fractional, B: Fractional](fDiff: A => B, initialSeed: A, initialStep: A, bEps: B) {
  val aFractional = implicitly[Fractional[A]]

  assert(initialStep.signum > 0)
  assert(fDiff(initialSeed) < fDiff(initialSeed + initialStep))

  @tailrec
  private def sweep(seed: A, step: A): A = {
    val bDiff = fDiff(seed)
    if (bDiff.abs < bEps) {
      seed
    } else if (bDiff.signum != step.signum) {
      sweep(seed + step, step)
    } else {
      val one = aFractional.one
      val newStep = step / aFractional.fromInt(-2)
      sweep(seed - newStep, newStep)
    }
  }

  private lazy val stepSign = aFractional.fromInt(-fDiff(initialSeed).signum)
  def apply: A = sweep(initialSeed, stepSign * initialStep)
}

val sweep = new Sweep((a: Double) => (a*a)-2, 1.0, 0.5, 1e-3)
println(sweep.apply, math.sqrt(2.0))
```

Note that to get things like `-2.0` in type `A`, you'll need to assemble them manually from `Fractional.one` or use `Fractional.fromInt`.

The other thing worth pointing out is the use of `math.Fractional.Implicits` and `Ordering.Implicits` which will allow you to use normal math syntax (+, <, /, etc.) instead of calling functions like `plus` and `div`.

Comment: Precisely. Thanks. And I can even use normal operators! One bug in my original code: "- newStep" should be "+ newStep" (makes the result come sooner).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the compiler to tell you when the type parameters `A` and `B` are not the same, just use one type parameter:

```
class Sweep[A: Numeric]( fDiff: A => A, initialSeed: A, initialStep: A, bEps: A )
```

Comment: Let me rephrase. The types may be the same, but the numbers mean different things. So I wish to hear if I do 'a+b' for example. To get the code working, I could skip all this, but I also try to understand Scala for real. :)

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand you. You wish two types to be the same type: so use *one* type

Comment: The A type usually means seconds, and B something else (i.e. speed). Thus they both are Double for the compiler, but cannot conceptually be counted together.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that you use `Double` here ...

```
val newStep = anum.toDouble(step) / -2.0
```

... although you want to use `Numeric` and actually use it that way in the next line.

For division, have a look at `Numeric`'s subtypes `Integral` and `Fractional`.

The compiler doesn't find an implicit evidence, because you explicitly pass none:

```
new Sweep((a: Double) => (a*a)-2, 1.0, 0.5, 1e-3)()
```

Removing the explicit empty parameter list fixes that:

```
new Sweep((a: Double) => (a*a)-2, 1.0, 0.5, 1e-3)
```

I'm not sure about the requirement of not mixing `A` and `B`, because you do that in multiple places in your code already.

I'm not sure this is what you want, but the following code works:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

class Sweep[A: Fractional](fDiff: A => A, initialSeed: A, initialStep: A, bEps: A) {
  val num = implicitly[Fractional[A]]

  assert(num.signum(initialStep) > 0)
  assert(num.lt(fDiff(initialSeed), fDiff(num.plus(initialSeed, initialStep)))) // check that it's an increasing function

  @tailrec
  private def sweep(seed: A, step: A): A = {
    val bDiff = fDiff(seed)

    if (num.lt(num.abs(bDiff), bEps)) { // done
      seed
    } else if (num.signum(bDiff) != num.signum(step)) {
      sweeimport scala.annotation.tailrec

class Sweep[A: Fractional](fDiff: A => A, initialSeed: A, initialStep: A, bEps: A) {
  val num = implicitly[Fractional[A]]

  assert(num.signum(initialStep) > 0)
  assert(num.lt(fDiff(initialSeed), fDiff(num.plus(initialSeed, initialStep)))) // check that it's an increasing function

  @tailrec
  private def sweep(seed: A, step: A): A = {
    val bDiff = fDiff(seed)

    if (num.lt(num.abs(bDiff), bEps)) { // done
      seed
    } else if (num.signum(bDiff) != num.signum(step)) {
      sweep(num.plus(seed, step), step) // continue, same step and direction ('bDiff' should go smaller)
    } else {
      val newStep = num.div(step, num.fromInt(-2))
      sweep(num.minus(seed, newStep), newStep) // reverse, smaller step
    }
  }

  // Make sure we take the initial step in the right direction
  private lazy val stepSign = -num.signum(fDiff(initialSeed))

  def apply: A = sweep(initialSeed, num.times(num.fromInt(stepSign), initialStep))
}

object TestX extends App {

  val t = new Sweep((a: Double) => (a * a) - 2, 1.0, 0.5, 1e-3)

  println(t, math.sqrt(2.0))
}

p(num.plus(seed, step), step) // continue, same step and direction ('bDiff' should go smaller)
    } else {
      val newStep = num.div(step, num.fromInt(-2))
      sweep(num.minus(seed, newStep), newStep) // reverse, smaller step
    }
  }

  // Make sure we take the initial step in the right direction
  private lazy val stepSign = -num.signum(fDiff(initialSeed))

  def apply: A = sweep(initialSeed, num.times(num.fromInt(stepSign), initialStep))
}

object TestX extends App {

  val t = new Sweep((a: Double) => (a * a) - 2, 1.0, 0.5, 1e-3)

  println(t, math.sqrt(2.0))
}
```

Comment: Yes, but since 'Numeric[T]' does not have division, I'm forced to. And there seems to be no way back from Double to A?