# Cannot create a Fractional from Double?

Tags: scala

This is a further question referring to [Problems with Scala Numeric[T]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839022/problems-with-scala-numerict).

I changed the code somewhat today, to support Newtonian estimation for the next best seed. All fine, except now the fact(?) of not being able to `A.fromDouble(v)` really kills.

It's a bit of a long sample, but probably best to place all here.

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
import math.{signum => sign}
import math.Fractional.Implicits._
import Ordering.Implicits._

/*
* 'f' is a "strictly increasing function" (derivative > 0).
* The sweep gives the value at which it gives 'goal' (within '+-bEps' margins).
*/
object NewtonianSweep {
  def apply[A: Fractional, B: Fractional]( 
    f: A => B, 
    fDerivate: A => Double, 
    goal: B, 
    bEps: B, 
    initialSeed: A, 
    aMin: A, 
    aMax: A 
  ): A = {

    assert( initialSeed >= aMin && initialSeed <= aMax )

    // 'goal' is supposed to exist within the range (this also checks that
    // the function is increasing - though doesn't (cannot) check "strict increasing",
    // we'll just trust the caller.
    //
    assert( f(aMin) <= goal )
    assert( f(aMax) >= goal )

    @tailrec
    def sweep( _seed: A ): A = {
      val seed= _seed.max(aMin).min(aMax)   // keep 'seed' within range

      val bDiff= goal-f(seed)    // >0 for heading higher, <0 for heading lower

      if (bDiff.abs < bEps) {
        seed                        // done (within margins)
      } else {
        val d= fDerivate(seed)      // slope at the particular position (dy/dx)
        assert( d>0.0 )

        // TBD: How to get the calculated 'Double' to be added to 'seed: A'?
        //
        val aType= implicitly[Fractional[A]]
        sweep( aType.plus( seed, aType.fromDouble( d*(bDiff.toDouble) ) ))
      }
    }

    sweep( initialSeed )
  }
}
```

The reason why I'm having two `Fractional` types, `A` and `B`, is that they are conceptually different. `A` usually is time. `B` can be anything. If I were to use the same type for them, I can just as well say they are `Double`'s.

Before I do that I wanted to check if anyone has the missing piece for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your distinction between `A` and `B`. But since you have `f: A => B`, I assume they can somehow be converted into each other? Then looking at the code, my impression is that `A` is the main type, so why not convert all `B` type things into `A` instead of the other way around?

Then you can spare any conversions to `Double`, that seems not a good idea anyway.

```
/*
* 'f' is a "strictly increasing function" (derivative > 0).
* The sweep gives the value at which it gives 'goal' (within '+-bEps' margins).
*/
object NewtonianSweep {
  def apply[A: Fractional, B: Fractional]( 
    // f: A => B, 
    fDerivate: A => A, 
    goal: B, 
    bEps: B, 
    initialSeed: A, 
    aMin: A, 
    aMax: A 
  )(f: B => A) : A = {

    assert( initialSeed >= aMin && initialSeed <= aMax )

    // 'goal' is supposed to exist within the range (this also checks that
    // the function is increasing - though doesn't (cannot) check "strict increasing",
    // we'll just trust the caller.
    //
    val aGoal = f(goal)
    val aEps  = f(bEps)

    assert(aMin <= aGoal)
    assert(aMax >= aGoal)

    val aType = implicitly[Fractional[A]]

    @tailrec
    def sweep(_seed: A): A = {
      val seed = _seed.max(aMin).min(aMax)   // keep 'seed' within range

      val aDiff = aGoal - seed    // >0 for heading higher, <0 for heading lower

      if (aDiff.abs < aEps) {
        seed                        // done (within margins)
      } else {
        val d = fDerivate(seed)      // slope at the particular position (dy/dx)
        assert(d > aType.zero)
        val prod = d * aDiff
        sweep(seed + prod)
      }
    }

    sweep(initialSeed)
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll try to explain. f is a function that provides i.e. a mapping from time to speed. Both are Double's but their meanings are different. That's why I thought to test if I can keep them separate in Scala (likely a bad idea). Changing all to A is fine but then I can just go the Double road. What I did, actually, is do 'type A=Double' and 'type B=Double' which allows the code to show which type something is. But there's no type checking if they get mixed. Yet, I still cannot see why Scala Fractional would not provide a 'fromDouble' (like it does 'fromInt'). Is there reason for such omission?

Comment: To answer your last question: You are not asking for a `Fractional[Double]` but `A`. How would Scala possibly know to construct such instance? This is impossibly unless you ask for a factory method. You could add a view `Double => A`, but I still think going through `Double` is the wrong idea. You can perfectly stay with `A` and `B` as long as you can bridge them.